# Scrolling to bottom of RecyclerView need to some delay then apply

Tags: android, scroll, android-recyclerview

I have a `RecyclerView` which contains `messages` item. I want to scroll to the bottom of layout when the user has pressed a button (like chat application). I have tried this piece of code but it does not work.I need this task done after a few millisecond.Because new message add to adapter in the asynchronous call retrofit.

```
 imgSend.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(edtMessage.getText().length()>0) {
                sentUserMessage();
                edtMessage.setText("");
                //I try this line or next line.None of them doesn't work
                linearLayoutManager.scrollToPositionWithOffset(messages.size(),0);
                recyclerView.scrollToPosition(messages.size());
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: You need to use `recyclerView.scrollToPosition(messages.size()-1);`

Comment: In this approach, RecyclerView scroll to two the last item Not last item

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
recyclerView.post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // Call smooth scroll  
        recyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(adapter.getItemCount().length());                                 
    }
});
```

Comment: It work. but I need this code done after a few millisecond.Because new message add to adapter in the asynchronous call retrofit.

Comment: @sarina you can add a progressDialog to show the user new data is uploading and scroll to the bottom when dialog.dismiss is called

Comment: This solution isn't suitable for me. Because my app is chat application and it isn't logical to show a progressDialog to user. User write a message and the activity should go to bottom where new massage is placed.